# how can I clean the line between two points in a panel

Tags: java, netbeans, panel, netbeans6.7

Hi
I have a panel that you can put some points one it and by clicking on a button ,lines will be drawn between points.also there is  a button that when you click on it ,all lines will be deleted and points will be on your panel (just lines are deleted) how can I do this.
is there any special method for this?
thanks

I work with netbeans ,AWT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option one: Draw the lines again, only this time in the "background color".  This won't work if your background isn't a solid color.

Option two: Redraw Everything, without the lines.  Not very efficient, but it really your only option if you have a complex background (text, images, etc).